# X570 mainboard (ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming 4) has two M.2 slots. Where to install system SSD?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, m.2

The ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming 4 mainboard has two M.2 slots specifically for SSD. Which should I use for the system boot SSD?

One is close to the PCIe slot for the graphics card. Is there any performance loss when I install the SSD (WD Black SN750 NVMe) in this slot because of PCIe lane sharing etc.? I could not find anything in the manual about that.

Comment: You should consult the motherboard's manual, which indicates which PCIe M.2 slots will or will not be available, depending on which PCIe slots are used

Comment: It is not written in the (quite superficial) manual.

Answer (score 0):

According to [your manual](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X570%20phantom%20Gaming%204/index.asp#Manual):

> 1 x Hyper M.2 Socket (M2_1), supports M Key type 2230/2242/2260/2280/22110 M.2 PCI Express module up to Gen4x4 (64 Gb/s) (with Matisse) or Gen3x4 (32 Gb/s) (with Pinnacle Ridge and Picasso)*
>   1 x Hyper M.2 Socket (M2_3), supports M Key type 2230/2242/2260/2280/22110 **M.2 SATA3 6.0 Gb/s module and** M.2 PCI Express module up to Gen4x4 (64 Gb/s) (with Matisse) or Gen3x4 (32 Gb/s) (with Pinnacle Ridge and Picasso)*

The only difference is that one of the sockets (M2_3, the one further from the graphics slot) supports SATA as well as PCIe SSDs.

Comment: That only tells what the slots support, not if there there are side effects on PCIe slot performance.

Comment: They both state up to 64Gb/s for PCIe, chances are whatever your SSD can support the slots will be fine with. I can't see any mention of side effects but the only way to know is to try it.

Comment: Per AM4 mb comparision spreadsheet, neither is listed as sharing bandwidth: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wmsTYK9Z3-jUX5LGRoFnsZYZiW1pfiDZnKCjaXyzd1o/htmlview#